# Gradle Build: Java - Compiler Error

Tags: java, gradle, build

I am trying to convert a multi-project maven build into gradle, and I am a struggling intern. I got the parent project to build successfully; however, I am struggling on a sub-project. When I ran 'gradle build' I first got an error reading:

```
error: Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later.
error: Target option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.

> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

So... I changed the following lines of my gradle.build from:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.5
targetCompatibility = 1.5
```

to:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

but now I get multiple errors saying

> cannot find symbol or ____ package does not exist

in the java files, which I was told to not mess with.
What can I do?

Comment: Read the error message (that you chose to obfuscate), and see where the symbol or package is defined, and why it can't be found. There is probably a dependency missing, or incorrectly defined. The error message is the key.

Comment: what is the installed jdk version? if java 9+, you might have many packages missing because of project jigsaw, specifically jaxb classes.

Comment: @gagansingh the java version on my laptop is 10.0.1, is that the problem?

Comment: you have not mentioned which packages were missing. jdk was divided into many modules in java 9 (project jigsaw) and some of the classes which were there in jdk by default are no more loaded by default. They can definitely be added very easily. one such example was jaxb classes. some javax classes were also moved to a different module. If this is your problem, then you need to add these dependencies in your gradle build.